# How to add Progress bar with percentage while inserting data to database?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

Here's my code for inserting data to database. I used Asynctask and HTTPUrlConnection. I want to achieve 0% - 100% progress dialog. Is there anyway to do that? I need that because I have also another activity that will insert images and file in the database. So i really have to display a progressbar for that.

```
private void registerDeveloper(String acctID, String devName, String devEmail, String devWebsite, String devLogo, String devStatus) {
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

        RequestHandler ruc = new RequestHandler();
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
         //   loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please Wait", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            df_SuccessDevRegistration dialogFragment = new df_SuccessDevRegistration();
            dialogFragment.show(fm, "Account not yet verified.");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

            String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

            HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("acctID", params[0]);
            data.put("devName", params[1]);
            data.put("devEmail", params[2]);
            data.put("devWebsite",params[3] );
            data.put("devLogo", uploadImage);
            data.put("devStatus", params[5]);

            String REGISTER_URL = DataClass.localAddress + "android_php/developer_register.php";
            String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(REGISTER_URL, data);
            return result;

        }


    }

    RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
    ru.execute(acctID, devName, devEmail, devWebsite, devLogo, devStatus);
}
```

then my PHP code:

```
<?php
        require_once('dbconnect.php');

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

         $acctID = $_POST['acctID'];
         $devName = $_POST['devName'];
         $devEmail = $_POST['devEmail'];
         $devWebsite = $_POST['devWebsite'];
         $devLogo = $_POST['devLogo'];
         $devStatus = $_POST['devStatus'];
         $id = 0;
         $fileName = $devName . '_' . $acctID. '.jpg';
         $devLogoLink = "android_php/dev_logo/$fileName";
         $devLogoLink2 = "../android_php/dev_logo/$fileName";



         $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
         $sql = "INSERT INTO tbldeveloper (acctID, devName,devEmail,devWebsite,devLogo,devStatus)VALUES('$acctID','$devName','$devEmail','$devWebsite','$devLogoLink','$devStatus')";

        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
         file_put_contents($devLogoLink2,base64_decode($devLogo));
         }


         mysqli_close($con);

        }else{
        echo 'error';
        }
```

Comment: In this kind of task you should decide over static progress values and set that to progress after completion of that task. For example, if you have 5 images to upload, set 20% when first image is uploaded, 35% when second image is uploaded, 58% when third image is uploaded and finally when 5th is uploaded mark it 100%, randomly like this will give user a feeling of work in progress. Even not just after uploading but you can update progress after each step too. Like after converting image to bytearray, then in between while preparing request string.

Comment: should I echo thru php the progress values? example after INSERT image into... then it will echo 20. something like that?

Comment: Progress bar is on Android side so you need to implement on android only.